# Android Layout folder for long screens

Tags: android, layout, directory, screen

I'm developing an android app to support all screen sizes, but when it come to long screens like 18:9 it giving me weird results in screen. I have following layout folders "layout,layout-large,layout-xlarge,layout-normal" and 18:9 screen ratio devices are using default settings of "layout" folder does android can have different kind of folder to place this type of layouts xml files only work with 18:9 screens. Or any other method to handle long screens.

My Layout folders are 
layout, 
layout-large,
layout-normal,
layout-xlarge,

In this image it shows how it overflow my text in 18:9 screen.

[image: Text overflow in 18:9 screen]

My activity_main.xml is here

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Main_layout"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/Head_layout">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Image_btn_home"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_head_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Hello Animals"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Image_btn_home"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/Image_btn_info"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Image_btn_info"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/info"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_container_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="365dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Head_layout">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

            android:id="@+id/View_pager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Navigation_layout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager_container_layout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/Navigation_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Head_layout">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Image_btn_left"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/left"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Image_btn_right"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/right"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            android:layout_marginStart="300dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Image_btn_play"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Image_btn_left"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/Image_btn_right"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

Comment: What are weird results exactly and what is the code producing those results? Please provide some more information for us to work with.

Comment: I am using `layout-sw720dp` for my 10" tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried using constraint layout? The best way to create a responsive layout for different screen sizes is to use ConstraintLayout as the base layout in your UI. ConstraintLayout allows you to specify the position and size for each view according to spatial relationships with other views in the layout. This way, all the views can move and stretch together as the screen size changes.